# Как проверить появление элементов внутри iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть iframe, он в какой то момент подгружает данные и вставляет в текущую страницу. И у этих данных есть html тэг. Как получить доступ к этим элементам которые были подгружены?

Такая проверка не даёт результата. Пишет что 0. Хотя элемент в браузере висит и его видно.

```
if($(".className").length)
```

Comment: так $('#ifrm').on('load', function(){ console.log('loaded'); }); пробовали?

Comment: для доступа к контенту так: $('#ifrm').contents()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к содержимому `iframe` нужно использовать функцию `contents()`.

```
$("#ifrmId").contents().find(".className")
```